# HTML code flows off page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this HTML code, it displays a twitter feed.. The only problem is, it flows off the page. I would like the feed to be 100% width and 600px height. I've fiddled with this for a while, and can make it work somewhat.. I think it needs to be one single code.
https://jsfiddle.net/33nw5jcd

```
<div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script> 
<script>
appreplicaapp = 'twitter';
appreplicaapikey = 'aa869d1f61a088e04e6fe1a66fc07933e404f9bb';
</script>
<script src="//api.appreplica.com/js/1/arc.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: If I'm not getting you wrong then you want to convert your CSS using Javascript right?

Comment: try this: `var a=document.getElementById("a")[0];`

Comment: @oserk and why is that? as getElById returns only one element so `[0]` is not required at all

Comment: @charieburns I guess you need a wrapper to your code like `onload/DOMContentLoaded`?

Comment: you are correct @Jai,, but I got this code that OP posted to be correct.. I don't get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
#a {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
#a::after {
   content: 'hello this is the last node';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="a">

</div>
```

**Note**: Try keeping your script after the element with id `a`. It may be a issue where your script executes before your element is rendered.

Comment: I've tried the HTML version both before, and after the second part of the code... Nothing. I don't think the CSS code can find it in the .tpl?

Comment: I don't get you

Comment: What the code did before is shorten the twitter feed so it doesn't flow off the page.