# HTML code flows off of page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this HTML code, it displays a twitter feed.. The only problem is, it flows off the page. I would like the feed to be 100% width and 600px height. I've fiddled with this for a while, and can make it work somewhat.. I think it needs to be one single code.
https://jsfiddle.net/33nw5jcd

```
<div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script> 
<script>
appreplicaapp = 'twitter';
appreplicaapikey = 'aa869d1f61a088e04e6fe1a66fc07933e404f9bb';
</script>
<script src="//api.appreplica.com/js/1/arc.js"></script>
</div>
```

This is the code that used to work to make it shorter..

```
<script>

var a=document.getElementById("a");
a.style.width=window.innerWidth;
a.style.height="600px";
a.style.background="ffffff";
var b="hello world";
var node=document.createTextNode("hello this is the last node");
 a.appendChild(node);

 </script>
```

The first code had`<div id="a">` when the code above was in use.

This is what I want it to look like.. (An older version of my site..)

http://thetwitterfeed.weebly.com/home

Comment: this jsfiddle does not do anything

Comment: @brk much like his profile picture :(

Comment: Works for me.... @brk

Comment: After looking at the Fiddle, it appears that all text on the page is within the window width. Am I missing something?

Comment: The width is not the problem, it's the tweets, they run down the page forever, I want it to stop at 600px.. @DawsonBotsford

Comment: well probably appreplica api is just feeding you data, which it outputs using `document.write`. So what have you done to make it work? Can you somehow specify a container?

Comment: Give the width of the iframe 100% and height fixed as 600px and also give the outer div too with overflow-y:scroll for this class "window"

Answer (score 2):

You already asked this question [HTML code flows off page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463920/htmlcodesae55544/43463969)

Check my fiddle:

```
#a {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
#a::after {
   content: 'hello this is the last node';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L3mwsp2o/1/

Comment: The code is great... But I was looking for something more like what an older version of my website looked like. http://thetwitterfeed.weebly.com/home

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning max-height to 600px. that would only show feed up till 600 px of height